# Simplest way to get youtube videos to be saved locally on an iPad

Tags: ipad, mac, youtube

When coming across certain youtube videos (on a Mac) I don't have time to watch at the moment, I wish I could get them saved for later offline viewing on my iPad.

Is there some simple setup I could make that with just 1-3 clicks the video will get saved to the iPad?

Comment: Why don't you add it to a playlist from the Youtube app itself?

Comment: @Gerry He says "for later **offline** viewing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify what web browser you use, but if you use FireFox a simple plugin like Easy You Tube Video Downloader may be just what you are looking for.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-youtube-video-downl-10137/

For Chrome you can use the following: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-your-videos/pipiejpiplliidbnncmckaljhhchoihc

- Step 1: Find YouTube Video
- Step 2 (Click 1): Click "Download" button
- Step 3 (Click 2): Drag Downloaded video into iTunes, dropping on iPad icon
- Step 4 (Click 3): Click "Sync" can be via USB or via WiFi
- Step 5: Watch videos in the Videos app on iPad

Comment: I use Chrome, but even with such an extension how would the downloaded file become automatically available for offline viewing on the iPad?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include chrome and step by step.  Your original questions says nothing about "automatically", it says with 1-3 clicks.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but it's an overly long process - you're forgetting about all of the clicks/keypresses for eg switching to finder, launching itunes, aligning the windows for the step 3 drag, etc

Comment: It only has to be one movement. I drag the downloaded file right off the Chrome download bar, to the iTunes icon on the dock, hover there for a moment 'til iTunes pops in front, then drop it on the iPad.

Comment: @Simon, here is a new one that should work: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-your-videos/pipiejpiplliidbnncmckaljhhchoihc

Comment: Great Thx  alot :)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Free Video Converter by Freemake now supports direct downloading of Youtube Videos. I have used previous versions of this software and it is excellent.

http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/

You can download any video to iTunes and then convert them directly to your iPad (aswell as other iOS devices). Its provides the easiest way (so they claim) to transfer Youtube to iTunes fast and free

http://www.freemake.com/how_to/how_to_download_youtube_video_to_itunes

I find it an invaluable tool for my other downloads (although have not used it in the above regard)